# Caching around 15k records during autosuggest

Tags: php, mysql, search, caching, kohana

I've got a form, which uses autosuggest to search around 15k records (store addresses) in the database. I'm using PHP (5.5 in dev, 5.4 in prod) and MySQL. My search algorhytm works in such way:

1. Assume query: `brand city`.
2. Explode query to keywords: `brand`, `city`.
3. Search database for `%brand%` or `%city%`.
4. Merge results, and sort them by wages (if any record occures in both arrays - wage of its increments).
5. Slice results to i.e. 10.
6. Send them back to the client.

I know, that is not so efficient, but it works well for < 1k records. I tried APC and memcached, but with that amount of data, I'm receiving memory leak.

Do you have any idea, how can I improve my search engine?
Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Example query:

```
SELECT `store`.`id` AS `id`, `store`.`user_id` AS `user_id`, `store`.`name` AS `name`, `store`.`tags` AS `tags`, `store`.`is_reported` AS `is_reported`
  FROM `stores` AS `store`
  WHERE `name` LIKE '%Å¼abka%'
  ORDER BY `store`.`name` ASC
```

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stores` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `tags` varchar(250) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `is_reported` int(1) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `id` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci AUTO_INCREMENT=11957 ;
```

And an example row:

> 11954 | 0 | Zielony Market - ul. Geodetów 76, 07-200 Wyszków | ul.,Geodetów,76,07-200,Wyszków | 0

Now I think, that I should create seperate columns for brand, city and street. Am I right?

Comment: you have an index on the column it was searching? 15k records is nothing. it should take milliseconds to return a search. even at millions of records, a search should take milliseconds as long as the database is structured efficiently.

Comment: Sounds like you need to optimize your code. This may be a question for the [Code Review Stack Exchange](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: where is the index then, mrhatesz? There's nothing about it in your create table result :/

Comment: nor is there anything about a city in that structure. i think it's very clear that any problem you are experiencing is an inefficiency in structure or query. it would be nice if you could edit your question and give us the query you are issuing and structure of tables that are being queried.

Comment: @skrilled done; now I see, that I misunderstood indexes idea...

Comment: Exactly. As long as you have indexes on what you are doing a select where on. I.e. if you are searching a cities table for zip_code, you'd want an index on zip_code. If things take a while even with an index, it's generally the query. At the end of the day, it would take several million records worth of data to make me look at other possibilities (such as hard drive throughput, doing caches on queries, etc)

Comment: Are you searching for both keywords in one query, or are you doing separate queries for each one – because you say you “merge” them afterwards and speak of “arrays”, I assume the latter? Do it in _one_ query. And where does the sorting by “wages” (whatever you mean by that resp. whyever you call it “wages”) happen – within the query/queries, or afterwards in the processing of the result? And _“Slice results to i.e. 10”_ also sounds if that only happens afterwards, outside of SQL – also not good.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my previous comment, it sounds like you might be doing multiple things wrong here at once.

I’d suggest trying it like this (after setting appropriate index on the `name` column, if that’s the only column you are searching in):

```
SELECT foo, bar, baz
FROM stores
WHERE name LIKE '%brand%' OR name LIKE '%city%'
ORDER BY (name LIKE '%brand%') + (name LIKE '%city%') DESC, name ASC
LIMIT 10
```

The sum of the two values in the ORDER BY will rank all matching records by *how many* of the searched words are found in their `name` column – in this context, MySQL will treat true as 1 and false as 0, so if both LIKE matches find a match, the sum will be 2, for just one it will be 1. Sorting alphabetically by store name itself only happens afterwards, because the number of found matches has higher priority for the relevance of a record.

Give that a go and see how it does please (don’t forget the index); if the performance is not great, then please edit your question to show us what an EXPLAIN statement for this query says (by putting EXPLAIN in front of the query, `EXPLAIN SELECT …` and executing it).

Comment: Thanks for that query, I'll give it a shot. And yes, I was performing two (at least) seperate queries. :(